# Multiple checkboxes hiding rows if TD doesn't contain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table containing td's with text.  I want to be able to filter each row based on checkbox values.  For example, if I select only one checkbox, it will look and filter out the rows that don't contain the value of the checkbox.  If I select two checkboxes, it will filter and only show the rows that contain both values of the checked boxes.  I can get it to partially work, but it will show the row if a checkbox value is present, regardless if a second checkbox is selected.  How can I get it to further filter when additional checkboxes are selected?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
var $ = jQuery
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
var showAll = true;
$('tr').not('.first').hide();
var checkedValues = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

$("tbody tr").hide();
for (var i = 0; i < checkedValues.length; i++) {
    showAll = false;
    $("td:contains('" + checkedValues[i] + "')").parent("tr").show();
}

if(showAll){
    $('tr').show();
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only need rows that contains **all** of the values of the checked checkboxes.

Try this:

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  var checkedValues = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  $("tbody tr")
  .hide()
  .filter(function() {
   var
    $tr = $(this),
    $tds = $.map(checkedValues, function(v) {
     return $tr.find('td:contains(' + v + ')').length > 0 ? v : null;
    });
    return $tds.length == checkedValues.length;
  }).show();

  if (checkedValues.length == 0) {
    $('tr').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#searchTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#searchTable td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="buh" value="buh">
<label for="buh">buh</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="dum" value="dum">
<label for="dum">dum</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="tss" value="tss">
<label for="tss">tss</label>

<table id="searchTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="first">
      <td>probably</td>
      <td>are</td>
      <td>headers</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>buh</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>dum</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>tss</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>buh</td>
      <td>dum</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>dum</td>
      <td>tss</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>buh</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>tss</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```